# Telegram WebApp работает на компьютере через офф клиент но если пробовать на IOS или на Android страница webapp не грузится

Tags: django, telegram, web-apps

Telegram WebApp работает на компьютере через офф клиент но если пробовать на IOS или на Android страница webapp не грузится.
приложение на django, запускаю в dev режиме с простыми сертификатами